# Ruby: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when trying to get Enumerator on an Array of Hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, enumerator

I am trying to loop on an Array of Hashes. When I reach the point where I fetch the Enumerator to start looping, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

My code looks like the following:

```
def extraireAttributs (attributsParam)
  classeTrouvee = false
  scanTrouve = false
  ownerOSTrouve = false
  ownerAppTrouve = false
  resultat = Hash.new(0)
  attributs = Array(attributsParam)

  attributs.each do |attribut| #CRASHES HERE!!!
    typeAttribut = attribut['objectTypeAttribute']
    [...]
```

I checked in debug mode to make sure the `attributsParams`argument and the `attributs`variable are not nil or empty. Both (because they are the same!) contain 59 Hashes objects, but I still cannot get an Enumerator on the Array.

Why do I keep on getting this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's there and not the following line?

Comment: Are you sure it's not on later code? It's hard to know without line numbers, could you provide line numbers?

Comment: How does `attributsParam` look like? If there are too many hashes, just show 3 of them!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`` undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass `` says you tried to do `something[index]` but `something` is `nil`. Ruby won't let you use `nil` as an array (ie. call the `[]` method on it).

The problem is not on the `attributs.each` line but on the line following which calls the `[]` method on `attribut`.

```
typeAttribut = attribut['objectTypeAttribute']
```

This indicates something in `attributs` is nil. This could happen if `attributsParam` is a list that contains nil like so.

```
attributsParam = [nil];
attributs = Array(attributsParam);

# [nil]
puts attributs.inspect
```

Simplest way to debug it is to add `puts attributs.inspect` just before the loop.

Also consider if you really need the `attributs = Array(attributsParam)` line or if it's already something [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html).

Comment: You are right. The inner structure of the hashes which are inside the outer array have changed. Therefore the exception happened inside the loop. Thanks a lot!