# i am geeting a :publishable_key => Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:stripe_publishable_key], error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

while starting a rails server i am geeting a following error can anyone help me in this.

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.2.2 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
C:/Users/anmoljain01/waroong-master/config/initializers/stripe.rb:2:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

  :publishable_key => Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:stripe_publishable_key],

   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:667:in `block in load_config_initializer'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:666:in `load_config_initializer'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:620:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Users/anmoljain01/waroong-master/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:42:in `require_relative'
        from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:76:in `log_to_stdout'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:36:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

also here is my  config\initializers\stripe.rb

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:stripe_publishable_key],

  :secret_key      => Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:stripe_secret_key]
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:stripe_secret_key]
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `Rails.application.credentials.stripe` is set up correctly? The error is saying `Rails.application.credentials.stripe` is nil, so you can't use it as an array (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514057/ruby-undefined-method-for-nilnilclass-when-trying-to-get-enumerator-on-an)

Comment: Thank you @smathy  I tried to do the same thing but it was giving me an error.

Comment: Tip: `rails credentials:edit` and confirm they're set correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It is specifically stating line 2 of your stripe.rb file is the issue.

Exiting C:/Users/anmoljain01/waroong-master/config/initializers/stripe.rb:2:in ': undefined method []' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

```
Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:stripe_publishable_key],
```

I would check your encrypted credentials file and ensure you have it in the correct format.  If you need to you can add it to your question just
**BE SURE TO TAKE OUT YOUR KEYS** if you do.

It should look something like:

```
stripe:
  stripe_publishable_key: 'my key number goes here'   (its a string so be sure you have quotes)
```